# Как можно реализовать такую структуру?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap

Как можно реализовать такую структуру? Желательно с Bootstrap

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: чтобы понять как это делать с bootstrap хорошо бы понять как это сделать без оного  - в данном случае у вас таблица с 2 столбцами и вы заполняете то правый то левый столбцы

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот вам самый простой пример timeline на основе таблицы без анимации:

*Состав: HTML+CSS

Время работы ~5мин*

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

table.timeline {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 500px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border-spacing: 0;
  height: auto;
}

table.timeline td:nth-child(odd) {
  position: relative;
  border-right: 3px dashed #e7f400;
  text-align: right;
}

table.timeline td:nth-child(odd):before {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: -9px;
  width: 14px;
  height: 14px;
  background: #00a5ff;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

table.timeline td {
  padding: 0 10px 50px 10px;
}

table.timeline h3 {
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #00a5ff;
  margin-top: -1px;
}

table.timeline p {
  font-size: 10px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #000;
}

h1,
h5 {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #000;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
```

```html
<h1>Пример</h1>
<table class="timeline">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td>
        <h3>Заголовок</h3>
        <p>Текст текст Текст текст Текст текст Текст текст Текст текст Текст текст Текст текст Текст текст Текст текст Текст текст Текст текст Текст текст</p>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <h3>Заголовок</h3>
        <p>Текст текст Текст текст Текст текст Текст текст Текст текст Текст текст Текст текст Текст текст Текст текст Текст текст Текст текст Текст текст</p>
      </td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td>
        <h3>Заголовок</h3>
        <p>Текст текст Текст текст Текст текст Текст текст Текст текст Текст текст Текст текст Текст текст Текст текст Текст текст Текст текст Текст текст</p>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <h3>Заголовок</h3>
        <p>Текст текст Текст текст Текст текст Текст текст Текст текст Текст текст Текст текст Текст текст Текст текст Текст текст Текст текст Текст текст</p>
      </td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td>
        <h3>Заголовок</h3>
        <p>Текст текст Текст текст Текст текст Текст текст Текст текст Текст текст Текст текст Текст текст Текст текст Текст текст Текст текст Текст текст</p>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<h5>Всё очень просто. Не правда ли?</h5>
```